# How to encrypt URL parameters in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, encryption, parameters

I'm trying to encrypt the URL parameters by implementing an EncryptedActionLink that returns a link with an encrypted parameter "p" to a generic action "ResolveUrl". The controller should recieve the request and invoke the proper action, or redirect it to the actual action without showing later the unencrypted values at the address bar (RedirectToAction doesn't work because of this).

So far, I've done this extension method:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString EncryptedActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var RouteValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);

        RouteValueDictionary.Add("actionName", actionName);
        RouteValueDictionary.Add("noise", new Random().Next(5000,10000));

        var routeValuesText = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, RouteValueDictionary).VirtualPath;            
        var Encryption64 = new Encryption64();
        var routeValuesTextCrypto = Encryption64.Encrypt(routeValuesText, "ABC123AB");

        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, "ResolveUrl", controllerName, new { p = routeValuesTextCrypto }, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

using this method, i get the following URL:

```
<%: Html.EncryptedActionLink("MyText", "MyAction", "MyContoller", new { Parameter1 = 123, Parameter2 = "String", Parameter3 = false }, null)%>

http://localhost:21536/MyContoller/ResolveUrl?p=iqo6yhy0Zl3jZXdMmnJ9KdvQhqCb5X6gg19%2FqZ8XUe19r5PJ6xO84plZr1GUHCHNY9h2SDO1o4CaF9W2DdmpywXooEQ1S0rNYjpnH4s3wb%2FqM8sGxoqAqyIoC%2F2nqW7U
```

Now, all my contollers inherits from ContollerBase. There I define the ResolveUrl Action as this:

```
public ActionResult ResolveUrl(String p)
        {
            var Encryption64 = new Encryption64();
            var query = Encryption64.Decrypt(p, "ABC123AB");

            if (query.Length > 2)
                query = query.Substring(2);

            var tokens = query.Split(new String [] { "&" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var RouteValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();

            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Count(); i++)
            {
                var centerPos = tokens[i].IndexOf("=");
                RouteValueDictionary.Add(tokens[i].Substring(0,centerPos),tokens[i].Substring(centerPos+1));
            }

            Type thisType = this.GetType();
            MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(RouteValueDictionary["actionName"].ToString());
            var theParameters = theMethod.GetParameters();
            var theParametersObject = new object[theParameters.Count()];

            System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter converter = new System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter();

            for (int i=0 ; i<theParameters.Count();i++)
            {
                theParametersObject[i] = converter.ConvertTo(RouteValueDictionary[theParameters[i].Name],theParameters[i].ParameterType);
            }

            return (ActionResult)theMethod.Invoke(this, theParametersObject);
        }
```

the thing about that code is that the ResolveUrl doesn't work. First, when there are two implementatios for one action (POST/GET) then an exception is throwed. And the second thing that fails is the parameter type conversion (for exampte converting from string to an nullable type).

How can I encrypt the URL parameters? Is any of my code useful? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I assume you've already modified your Routes to use to 'p' parameter as a required parameter?

Comment: sure, "p" is the required parameter for ResolveUrl. The ResolveUrl gets executed but it thows errors because of the casting and the "overloaded" action name

Comment: Is HTTPS usable at all? Parameters and everything but the IP/port is encrypted automatically then.

Comment: i don't know, can you post an example? will the links be encrypted as well?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to encrypt url parameters (route values) you can use custom valuedataprovider that will automatically decrypt the value on action without showing unencrypted value in address bar.